# Compare two primary keys (Access database) with ASP

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, ms-access

I have two open queries from one Access 2010 database. I'm using ASP.

I want to simply compare the primary key fields in ASP with an `IF… THEN` statement.
They look the same on screen when I display, but it just throws up an error when I try and compare them.

Can I convert them to a value?

```
IF rsdata4("ID") = rsdata("ID")
    THEN Response.Write ("XXX")
END IF
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if possible, I would suggest that you re-execute the sql used to fill both table objects into ONE single new query. It will run faster, but also tend to be a lot less code. So do a relational “join” between the two tables.

I suppose you can loop over each row in table A, and look for it in table B.

And, there is a filter/select command for a table object, so it would at least eliminate the 2nd loop.

So, you should be able to use this code:

We are going to look for and find “ID” from table A, and find it in table B.

```
    Dim OneRow As DataRow
    Dim FoundValues() As DataRow
    For Each OneRow In tableA.Rows
        FoundValues = tableB.Select("ID = " & OneRow("ID"))
        If FoundValues.Length > 0 Then
            Debug.Print("Found for ID = " & OneRow("ID"))
            ' found one
        End If
    Next
```